# How do I create a multi-line header?

Tags: header-footer

If you imagine a two-lines header, I'd like to have `\chead` writing in the upper line and `\lhead` and `\rhead` in the lower line. (I know, they're single-lined, that was for explanation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\fancyhead[C]{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\centering center here\vspace{10pt}\\\phantom{.}\end{minipage}}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark\vspace{-8pt}}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark\vspace{-8pt}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section{test 1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{test 2}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

May be if there are no headers left and right but there is a center header, you have to redefine the center header to not add space that other headers will not come to reduce.